# Random 100 char array; Print all array values

Tags: java, arrays

So I am trying to make an array that stores 100 random characters (between a and z). I then want to print all of the characters so the user can see them.

Here are two of my methods to do just that:

```
//method to generate random character between ch1 and ch2
   public static char getRandomCharacter(char ch1, char ch2)
   {

      return (char) (ch1 + Math.random() * (ch2 -ch1 +1));

   }

//==========================================   

   //method to assign generated characters (between a and z) to a 100 character array
   public static char createArray()
   {

      //declare a 100 character array
      char[] character = new char[100];

      //for loop assigning the random characters to the array using getRandomCharacter method
      for (int x = 0; x < character.length; x++)
      getRandomCharacter('a', 'z');

      //for loop outputting the characters in the array
      for (int x = 0; x < character.length; x++)
      System.out.println(character[x]);

      return character[1];

   }
```

My problem is, whenever I compile my program, it outputs all 100 values as "0000". Am I missing something what would make it output as the zeros instead of a random character? I can add in my main method if that is required to figure this out.

I am also wondering, what would I use for the return statement? I just have it returning the first character in the array. The program would not compile if I left the return statement out (because it is a chat method), and it has to have a method type for me to call the method from my main.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You never assign any values to `character`. In your first `for` loop, I think what you meant to include was `character[x] = getRandomCharacter('a', 'z');`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getRandomCharacter()` returns a random char, but you are not storing that in your `character` array.

Try replacing this:

```
getRandomCharacter('a', 'z');
```

with this:

```
character[x] = getRandomCharacter('a', 'z');
```

Comment: Thank you so much, now all the characters print just fine. Any idea as to what I should use as my return statement? I'm just calling the createArray() method from my main to output all of the values. Is there something I can use as the return statement that would capture all of the characters? If that makes any sense..

Comment: Nevermind actually. I realized I can just set it as a void method instead of a char method, then remove the return statement.

Comment: It could just return the entire array: `return character;`. You'd have to change the method signature as well, to: `public static char[] createArray()`. Or, you could return `void`, as you said. It all depends on what you need.

Answer (score 0):

if all you need to do is print the elements, then you dont need to return anything

```
public static void createArray()
   {

      //declare a 100 character array
      char[] character = new char[100];

      //for loop assigning the random characters to the array using getRandomCharacter method
      for (int x = 0; x < character.length; x++)
      character[x] = getRandomCharacter('a', 'z');

      //for loop outputting the characters in the array
      for (int x = 0; x < character.length; x++)
      System.out.println(character[x]);

   }
```

Answer (score -1):

To answer your second question, you change the return type of your `createArray()` function to `void` instead of `char` and then omit the return statement.